# Meaning of using 'eager:true' option in TypeORM

Tags: typescript, typeorm, eager-loading, node.js-typeorm

I've been using TypeORM and I've got some problem when pushing data as follows:

- `User.ts` (Entity)

  ```js
  @OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.user)
  posts: Post[]
  ```
- `Post.ts` (Entity)

  ```js
  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.posts)
  user: User
  ```

And when I tried to do **Create Post** like this:

- `createPost.ts`

  ```js
  // Some Codes...

  // Save Post
  const post =  Post.create({
    title: title,
    content: content
  })
  await post.save()

  // Update User
  const user = await User.findOne({ uid: ctx.uid })
  user.posts.push(post)  // ****************** PROBLEM ******************
  await user.save()
  ```

As I marked **PROBLEM** above, when I requested this, I got `Cannot call method 'push of undefined` error.

But luckily I could've solved this by just adding following option at `User.ts` file:

```js
@OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.user, {
  // -------------- added --------------
  eager: true
  // -----------------------------------
})
posts: Post[]
```

And I'd like to know why this works... I've read the typeorm document about [Eager](https://typeorm.io/#/eager-and-lazy-relations), and it says

> Eager relations only work when you use find* methods. If you use QueryBuilder eager relations are disabled and have to use leftJoinAndSelect to load the relation. Eager relations can only be used on one side of the relationship, using eager: true on both sides of relationship is disallowed.

But I'm not sure what the last sentence means.

> eager: true on both sides of relationship is disallowed.

So, I've disallowed the relation between `User` and `Post`, and the file now can understand `user.posts` is defined?

Could somebody please help me with this...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in the [Eager Loading Documentaion](https://typeorm.io/#/eager-and-lazy-relations) You can set the `eager: true` on one side of the relationship only. That means you have define the relationship like below.

in `User.ts`

```js
@OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.user, { eager: true })
posts: Post[]
```

and in `Post.ts`

```js
@ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.posts)
user: User
```

And in here if you use `await User.findOne({ uid: ctx.uid })` in functions that will load Post relationship automatically. This does not mean you cannot use the vice versa relationship. From `Post` to `User` relationship you can load the relationship still using `leftJoinAndSelect`.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! So when `await User.findOne({ uid: ctx.uid })` runs, it automatically fetch data because they are related. And because they already loaded related data from `Post`, `user.posts` is not `undefined` any more?

+) About the `eager: true` option, I can only set that option in one side, but still can grab data from either side? Either from `User`, get related `Post` or from `Post`, get related `User`? Did I understand what you mean?

Comment: And if I need to use `eager: true` option to make `user.posts` to be **defined** , do I have to add `eager: true` option for all `@OneToMany()` relationship..? If so, could I ask you one more thing? Could you please give an answer for why not TypeORM set that option by default...? Or any other references would be soooo grateful!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Yes @TonyPark. You understood my point. eager loading means related data is automatically fetched. And even you used `eager: true` or not, still you can load the relationships using `Querybuilder`.

Comment: Very Well. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: if you enabled `eager: true` in the Entity and need to get results without it ( without reflecting the `eager` flag ), you can use `loadEagerRelations: false` and the find method.


`Entity..find({ loadEagerRelations: false });`


https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/f5b93c14b5efa1a55aed0211a4757af1b3d6e66b/src/find-options/FindOneOptions.ts#L108